# Are email-forwarding services safe to use

Tags: email, email-server, mail-forwarding

Basically can services like [this](https://github.com/forwardemail/free-email-forwarding) snoop into my emails, even if it is an open-source system (i.e. server code may not match open source code)?

Are there further resources I can read to feel more comfortable using services like these?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. Email itself is not very secure, and you mention services, but only link to one source repository.

Comment: @barbecue I just want to know if email forwarding services can read my emails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet email is inherently [not very secure](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/can-email-ever-be-secure/), and does not encrypt the content of messages. Any service that stores or forwards your email **can** read it. Whether or not they **will** read it is a question you need to ask the individual service provider, but there is no technical reason why they could not read it unless you take extra steps to encrypt the message.

While it is possible to add encryption to email, there's no single standard way to do so, and both the sender and recipient need to use the same method.

SMTP can use secure channels for transmission, but that only protects against snooping the traffic while it's in transit, it does not protect the text of the message once it arrives at the server.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the one service you mention is in its [documentation](https://forwardemail.net/#/?id=can-you-read-my-forwarded-emails):

> **Can you read my forwarded emails:**
>
> No, I cannot read your emails and I have no wish to. Many other email forwarding providers unethically read your email. This is not what I'm about.
>
> The code that is deployed to the server is publicly visible on GitHub!

For other services there is no answer that will fit all services. Some are open source and you can look for yourself, others have privacy agreements.

The best is to find a service that has included in its Terms and Conditions that it does not keep a copy of your emails or do anything else with your emails.

On further resources the only answer really is the documentation and/or Terms and Conditions *for that service*. Although in general email [is not very secure](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/can-email-ever-be-secure/).